# jQuery Hover - add buffer to div trigger area

Tags: jquery, hover

Sort of a weird question... Can you add a buffer or space to a div using hover? For instance, if you hover over a div, but you want to add a 10px padding or buffer to that div, so that when you hover over the edge it doesn't trigger the hover action, unless you go past the 10px inner buffer of the div. Hope that makes sense. It's basically a buffer zone on the div that's hoverable.

```
$( '#divA' ).hover(function() {
    $( '#divB' ).removeClass( 'active' );
});

$( '#divB' ).hover(function() {
    // can you any type of margin/buffer to this?
    $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
});
```

Here's a Fiddle to demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/0ka3t9my/1/

Note: Basically want the hover action to fire once mouse passes yellow area, but wanted to accomplish this without the extra div, maybe using some sort of JS to figure that out, but maybe that's not possible?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ you can use the .css() method to accomplish this. give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better method/solution to this issue:

https://github.com/john-terenzio/jQuery-Hover-Delay